# Applying "reset" styles on *

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-reset

Are there any drawbacks of applying global styles to all elements?

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: ok i did, so is the performance argument real, because some of the  answers contradict each other? And if the other reason against it is form elements, then it's ok to use it if my form elements don't need the default browser styling?

Comment: If `*` is just one charachter beside include all tags wich include a lot of charachters increasing the size of the file .... I don't see in the duplicates some about performance just about affect unexpected elements. Anybody knows a link that talk about performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` is so-called 'heavy' selector. But unfortunately there is no* other way to apply border-box model to all elements in a couple lines of code.
Talking about padding/margin and list-style reset - better use some common techniques from [www.cssreset.com/](http://www.cssreset.com/)

*Border-box can be applied here, in Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `font: inherit;` seems useful too, it prevents the browser from applying random fonts to input elements